# Dynamically allocate an array from a textfile and retain its values

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

After looking at some other similar questions, this is what I've written so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
      
void read_from_file() {
    
    int* arr;
    int length;
    std::string file_name = "data.txt";
    std::ifstream file_data;
    file_data.open(file_name.c_str());

    if (file_data.is_open())
    {
        file_data >> length;
        arr = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            file_data >> arr[i];
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }

        file_data.close(); 
    }
    else 
        std::cerr << "Cannot open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
}
```

All good here, until I try to manipulate the array's values. For example, I have to check if the array is sorted in ascending order. I don't know how to get back where I read the array and get the values.

```cpp
bool check_if_sort_asc(int* arr, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] > vect1[i + 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
    
int main()
{
    int *arr;
    int length;
    read_from_file();
    if (check_if_sort_asc(arr, length)==true)
        std::cout << " The array is sorted in ascending order  ";
    else
        std::cout << "The array is not sorted in ascending order ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this a text file, please show sample data

Comment: You likely want `read_from_file()` to `return` something.  Currently, it reads to a local variable, then destroys that variable and leaks the memory.

Comment: you really really need to use std::vector

Comment: the data is put in a single line, for example 5 12 15 7 3 1 where 5 is the dimension and the other numbers are array's values

Comment: What is `vect1` supposed to be?  Your code seems to think it's something array-like, but no variable named `vect1` is declared anywhere.

Comment: vect1 is arr. i forgot to change the name there. sorry

Comment: In addition to using `std::vector`, you could also use [`std::is_sorted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) to entirely replace one of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate fix is this

Change read_from_file to return the data it read

```
int * read_from_file() {
    int *arr = NULL;
```

then return arr at the end of it

```
    else 
       std::cerr << "Cannot open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
   return arr;
}
```

and finally use the returned value in main

```
arr = read_from_file();
```

and free it when you have finished

```
delete [] arr;
```

But your code doesnt compile, because of that vect1 stuff, plus you should use std::vector.

As Bob_ points out you need the length too, so either

- use std::vector
- make the arr array one bigger and place the length as first entry
- use std::vector
- pass a length int by reference into read_form_file (see below)
- use std::vector

ie

```
int * read_from_file(int * length) {
    int *arr = NULL;
...
        file_data >> *length;
```

But mainly, use std::vector